# Should you use en dashes in acronyms?

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms, dashes

For terms like liquid chromatography–mass spectrometry that typically use an en dash rather than a hyphen, would an en dash still be used in the acronym, LC–MS? Or would we only need a hyphen there, LC-MS?

EDIT: Anybody have a style guide that speaks to this issue?

Comment: Why not just LCMS and be done with it?

Comment: I think there's some clarity added by the punctuation because LC and MS are independent techniques.

Comment: Most initialisms are free of dashes.

Comment: Typography is language independent (not an English question). Suggest you try at [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: @MετάEd I disagree that how one writes initialisms is somehow off-topic here. This is not “mere” typography. Go down that road and you’ll be saying that using hyphens for dashes and vice versa is off-topic, and that’s just wrong.

Comment: This is a style issue, but en-dashes are for ranges not phrases. Note also that these techniques are referred to as *hyphenated mass spectrometric* in literature.

Comment: I *suspect* they are trying to avoid people construing chromatography-mass as a phrasal adjective.

Comment: @horatio En dashes are often used in circumstances other than ranges. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Relationships_and_connections) for example and a _lengthy_ discussion of style guides [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia_talk:Manual_of_Style&oldid=429824164#Style_guides).

Comment: @CraigW: style should always be sacrificed for clarity. Your links call this sort of thing a last resort use.

Comment: @horatio The en dash _is_ for clarity, not style.

Comment: @craigw: Please reread my previous responses.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the judges are still out on this one. I did a quick search on the web, and found all sorts of variations on the abbreviation, so you can take your pick: LC-MS, LC–MS, and LC/MS were the most common. Perhaps your authors have a preference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a style issue with your publication.  If your pub has no defined style for this, then pick one, and be consistent.  Few people are even aware of the distinction between hypen, endash, emdash, but they are quick to spot when it's not the same in consecutive paragraphs.